# why is UnkownOperatorException not being thrown?

Tags: java, exception

The UnknownOperatorException should be thrown when the user enters anything besides one of the following +-*/PR
However, it does not seem to be functioning correctly. Here is a sample output.

```
Enter an operator and a number:
+5
Enter an operator and a number:
g9
5.0
```

The main class never specifically outputs the message, but the method which the exception is being thrown does...so if the exception is caught shouldn't the message be printed?

Here is my main class:

```
public class Main{ 

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        Calculator a = new Calculator(0);

            a.setNumber(a.aResult(a));
            a.setNumber(a.aResult(a));


        String theString = String.valueOf(a.getNumber());
        System.out.println(theString);

}
}
```

This is the method that calls the method which throws the exception

```
public void whatOperator() throws Exception
    {

        String operatorString = null;
        operatorString = enterNumber();
        // shouldn't this test the string and throw the exception if       needed?
        throwOperatorException(operatorString);
        if(operatorString.substring(1).equals(""))
        {
            switch(operatorString){
                 case "R":
                    result = RESET;
                    break;
                case "P":
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        else    
       theNumber = Double.parseDouble(operatorString.substring(1));
        char theOperator = operatorString.charAt(0);
        this.operator = theOperator;
        operatorString ="";
        operatorString += theOperator;


        switch(operatorString){
        case "*":
        result = getNumber() * theNumber;
        break;
        case "/":
        result = getNumber() / theNumber;
        break;
        case "+":
        result = getNumber() + theNumber;
        break;
        case "-":
        result = getNumber() - theNumber;
        break;

    }

}
```

lastly the exception method itself. Somehow it is not being thrown. I think it has to do with the if statement nested within it but I am unsure how to fix this.

```
public void throwOperatorException(String entry) throws Exception
    {
        char oneOperator;
        for(int i = 0; i < ALL_OPERATORS.length();i++)
        {
            oneOperator = ALL_OPERATORS.charAt(i);
        if(entry.charAt(0) != oneOperator && i == ALL_OPERATORS.length())
        {
            try{
                throw new UnkownOperatorException(entry);

            }catch(UnkownOperatorException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

this is ALL_OPERATORS

```
private final String ALL_OPERATORS = "+-*/RP";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

```
i == ALL_OPERATORS.length()
```

would never be true(or always is `false`), why? Ask yourself if you loop inside

```
for(int i = 0; i < ALL_OPERATORS.length();i++)
```

would that ever happen?

---

So the code within your `if` is never reached and hence the `UnkownOperatorException` is never thrown.

---

The other way to check if `String` entry's first character is one amongst the `ALL_OPERATORS` is to use [`contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: @mark1092 should work, though it's not guaranteed unless you give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your structure. Don't name a method `throwXxException` unless that's its only job. It's better to have an enum approach that separates concerns:

```
public enum Operator {
  PLUS("+") {
    @Override int op(Integer args ...) {
      return args[0] + args[1];
    }
  },
  MINUS("-") { // similarly ...
  },
  // etc.
  ;

  private final String symbol;

  abstract public int op(Integer args ...);

  Operator(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
  }

  public static Operator fromString(String entry) {
    final String symbol = entry.substring(0, 1);
    for (Operator operator : values) {
      if (symbol.equals(operator.symbol)) {
        return operator;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  // @Override public String toString() etc.
}
```

Obviously I left out error-checking here and there.

Don't throw the exception from the enum! Throw it from the code that gets back a `null` from `fromString`.

Don't ever let us catch you using `throws Exception` or `catch (Exception ...)` again.

Comment: It's worth reading ahead in the Java tutorial, and the example here might give some hints as to its power.